# how to get selected options value in php/javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to get html slected option value in php or javascript.

I am trying to do is:

```
<form action="book-page-1.php>" method="POST">
  <select name="chosePage">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">    
</form>
```

What I want is to pass the selected page number in **"form action"** before submitting the form like:

```
// I want to pass selected option value in "url" before submit the form
<form action="book-page-<?php echo selected option;?>.php>" method="POST">
```

I dont want in php post like:

```
  // This is not my requirement - Because I want to pass value in "url" before submit the form
 if (isset($_POST['chosePage'])) {
     $op = $_POST['searchItemname'];
 }
```

I want to pass the selected option value in url.
PHP or JAVASCRIPT all are welcome.

Any Idea would be welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Since you are submitting a form from client side, you need to do this with JavaScript. One way to do this will be to add an eventListener to your select’s change event and then change the post action url when user selects an option.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an id to the `<select>` element, `<select id="chosePage "name="chosePage">`.
then using javascript you can do:

```
let selected = document.getElementById("chosePage").value;
```

Comment: thanks for the response nut how to pass this value in url? Not able to change the value of url before submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by this simple function :

```js
function SandRequest(){
  let selected = document.getElementById("chosePage").value;
  document.getElementById("MyForm").setAttribute("action", "book-page-"+selected+".php");
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="MyForm" method="post" >
  <select id="chosePage" name="chosePage">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  
  <input name="Booktitle" type="text">

    <button onclick="SandRequest()" >Update</button> 
</form>
```